# swift uiview does not have a member named center and not convertible to UIView

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I made a array of de model class 'fish' and want to display on the view when my view did load. I got the error message:

'Fish' does no have a member named 'center'
'Fish' is not convertible to 'UIView'

Please see my code below. I will appreciated any kind of help. Thanks

Here my custom class:

```
class Fish {
var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "fish_3"))
}
```

Here my View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var fishes:[Fish] 

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fishes = [Fish]() 

    var fish3 = Fish()
    fish3.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "fish_3"))
    fishes.append(fish3)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for fish in fishes {
    var x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(120))
    var y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200))
    fish.center.x = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    view.addSubview(fish)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why do you think fish is a view? Why not just have a array of image views?

Comment: typo:fish.center.x = CGPoint(x: x, y: y) --> fish.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y). I still have the same errors.

Comment: Please correct the question rather than adding comments

Comment: Fish is an UIImageView. but why Swift tell me that fish is not a view. I need to add the fish to my view.

Comment: Because fish is not an image view with how your code is now. You must make it a subclass of UIImageView for it to be a UIImageView

Comment: Perfect!! You help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fish should inherit from UIView somehow and the best way to do this is to make it a subclass of UIImageView

```
class Fish: UIImageView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Setup
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // Setup
    }
}
```

now when you initialize it:

```
var fish3 = Fish(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
fish3.image = UIImage(named: "fish_3")
fishes.append(fish3)
```

Comment: With this answer, you can actually just set `fish.center` instead of always having to reference the imageView `fish.imageView.center`, and you're adding the entire fish as an object to your view and not just it's imageView

Answer (score 1):

```
fish.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
view.addSubview(fish.imageView)
```